# Push segue works from one collection view not second modal does work

Tags: ios, iphone, push

I have an app  iOS 7  that starts with one collection view- then branches to one of two collections view each one with a push with imbedded Nav controller in the first.  Both collections view then feed to the same view where a detailed picture is displayed.  In the first one I can use a push and everything works fine.  I added the second one and when I use the push it logs going to the new view but its immediate back to original view.  If I switch the segue to modal it works fine.

Here is the code for the working one

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Battles" sender:nil];

  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Battles"]){
        FDRImageViewController*destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"IAM here");
        destViewController.specificship = _specificship;
    }
```

The one that is not working --

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Generals" sender:nil];
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Generals"]) {
        FDRImageViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"IAM here Battleship");
         NSLog(@"specificship = %@",_specificship);
        destViewController.specificship = _specificship;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I'd check the segue identifiers one more time and make sure they aren't dupes.

Comment: I discovered the problem was in the first Collection View where I was missing an if statement and sending two segues at once.  It was going to the write place since that was first, but it was also generating a second segue request that was causing the problem down the line